# Javascript Best way to deal with server returning enum numbers? Am I only limited to use switch statements to convert them to string?

Tags: javascript

Server returns me things like 0,1,2,3,4..etc corresponding to something like: 0 = "Hello", 1 = "How", 2 = "Big Data" that I would need to display on the front end.

Sorry if this was asked before, but I don't know what this would be called. Thus not able to find answers.

Is my only option to write a switch statement?

```
switch(status){
 case 0:
  return "Hello";
 case 1: 
  return "How";
 ...etc
}
```

I don't have the option to change server code to return strings, but would that be a better way? as in returning both the number and the string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use objects or arrays and return them.

```js
var strings = ["Hello", "How", "Big Data"];
var status = 0;
console.log(strings[status]);
```